# Codeigniter 2.x : adding tags to my entries

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building an application where an user may add notes. I would like the user to be able to add some tags for the notes and filter it afterwards. So far I allow the user to use work with string and filter with LIKE %% . But it doesnt fully fulfil my needs, because when there are more tags, I might need to search not all of them, use operators etc. An example: stackoverflow tags.

I was thinking about the following SQL structure

- have a table called 'notes' with column called 'tag_id'
- have a table called 'tags' which provides the 'tag_id' with 'text'
- a function that translates each array (forward and backward) and replaces it with the opposite equivalent [numbers <=> tag translations for front end, and tag translations <=> number for the database and following filtering]

The question is: Is it a good idea to do it like this? How should I structure my database? Do you know about any particular articles that could help me?

Comment: You can get out with just 3 tables: notes, tags, notes_tags (foreign keys: note_id,tag_id). No functions, just queries

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have one note with many tags, I suggest you reverse the way you are tracking the relationship. In other, words have:

table note
- field noteid
- field notename

table tag
- field tagid
- field noteid
- field tagname

if you want a many to many relationship then store the relationship in a third table which would have 3 columns: 1) linkid 2) tagid 3) noteid .

you can then either retrieve all tags for a particular by querying tag table where noteid=noteid or doing a join of the tables - the actual join will depend on what you are trying to do